How can I improve mobile performance on a Webflow site with heavy third-party scripts and large CDN styles?
I'm facing serious performance issues on my Webflow site, particularly on mobile devices. The site takes a long time to load on mobile, and I need to optimize it for better speed and performance within a short deadline. It’s a services website, so speed is crucial for user experience and SEO rankings.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Compressed images to reduce size.
Limited animations to avoid heavy rendering.
Added the defer attribute to scripts to load them after the page content.
Despite these efforts, the site still performs poorly. There are several third-party integrations (e.g., analytics, widgets) and a large CDN that contains CSS styles, which I suspect could be part of the problem. I'm not sure how to optimize these or whether they’re the main cause.
I’d appreciate any advice on:
Identifying whether custom code or third-party scripts are causing the slow performance.
Best practices for handling large CDN CSS files on Webflow.
Additional techniques or tools I can use to debug and improve performance on mobile.
I’m on a tight deadline, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]. Your question in it's current state is way too broad to be answerd. Furthermore asking recommendations on tools, tutorials, etc. is off-topic on StackOverflow

A trick I've used to handle remote CSS styles is using this format:
<link 
rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@your-cdn.css" 
media="print" 
onload="this.media='all'">

This asynchronously loads the CSS and can sometimes improve performance.
Also, I wouldn't get too bogged down with performance optimisation — if your website requires certain libraries then at times you have to take the performance hit because doing that is worth it for an improved user experience. Additionally, these performance audit tools are only there to provide recommendations based on average internet speed. Your clientele base more often than not has much faster internet so the audit isn't truly reflective of the real user experience. So I would improve what I can based on the recommendations without forfeiting the user experience.
If you want to get more technical I would strongly advise the Finsweet dev starter since it lets you compile your code locally so you only import the parts of a library that you actually need, thus improving performance.
I hope this hasn't found you too late! All the best with your project
